# Cauchy's theorem with partially defined contour and function

Tags: complex-analysis

The Cauchy's theorem says if $f(z)$ is analytic on and inside the contour $C$, then,$$\oint_C f(z)dz=0$$ And if we split the contour into two segments $A$ and $B$, we may obtain $$\oint_C f(z)dz=\int_Af(z)dz +\int_Bf(z)dz=0$$ So, $$\int_Af(z)dz=-\int_Bf(z)dz$$ Here is the part making me curious. If we only know the value of $f(z)$ on the segment $A$, but are otherwise free to define $f(z)$ at any point that is not on $A$ (as long as it is analytic), we end up something very weird. The left hand side of Equation 3 is something definite, but since we can freely vary $B$ and define the value of $f(z)$ outside $A$, the right hand side looks very indefinite. And there can be numerous different combination of $f(z)$ and $B$ outside $A$. So it means no matter how we choose, we end up the same for the integral. Shall I accept this counter-intuitive result or I make something wrong in my reasoning? Thanks in advance!

Edit: I find Lourenco Entrudo`s reply is quite helpful in understanding these. And thanks everyone for helping!

Comment: You cannot split a closed loop integral into two segments. Rather in two open curves $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$.

Comment: You cannot in general freely define $\;f\;$ on or outside$\;A\;$ and expect the function to be analytic in the\ whole domain...

Comment: If the function is analytic in the whole domain, the values in A pretty much set the values in B in stone. The condition of holomorphism is very strong; one can get a feel for it by looking at the Cauchy-Riemann equations and the extra condition that the partial derivatives be continuous

Comment: Some functions actually has _natural boundaries_ that prevent any methods from analytically continuing these functions beyond these boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is that it doesn't come up: If you know the values of $f$ on $A$ and $f$ is analytic then you are **not** free to choose the values on $B$. Since $A$ has a limit point in the domain, if $f_j$ are analytic and $f_1=f_2$ on $A$ then also $f_1=f_2$ on $B$.